# Cloud job discovery gives error?

Tags: cloud

When i heat below api i got below error ?

https://jobs.googleapis.com/v2/companies?key=API_KEY

Request :

```
{
 "displayName": "Test Display Name",
 "distributorCompanyId": "123456",
 "name": "Test Name",
 "careerPageLink": "Test Career",
 "companySize": 50,
 "distributorBillingCompanyId": "Test Billing ",
 "eeoText": "Test eeoText",
 "hiringAgency": true,
 "title": "Ordex Technology solutions",
 "disableLocationOptimization": false
}

{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Tenant is not recognized or not allowed to access the method. Request ID for tracking: 20fea5c2-4299-4f58-8445-d0e99d1c3673:APAb7ITREz3q4gqybYf4qbwDwHkj+Klo4g==",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

Comment: Having the same problem. While doing the search.

Comment: First authenticate with authe 2.0 and after getting bearer token use this token and send request than it will working fine.

Comment: Also if you are using java than you can easily use default jar file for create companies , job etc.

Comment: Thank you Mahesh. Do you have any official documentation for this specific token generation?

Comment: @MaziarAboualizadehBehbahani no but you can use postman rest client it will be easy